# Sum Function at ASP Page

Tags: sql, asp.net, sum

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT SUM(Summe), ItemObjektID FROM [Item] GROUP BY ItemObjektID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
             Items:<br /><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ItemObjektID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8">
         <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemObjektID" HeaderText="ItemObjektID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ItemObjektID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Summe" HeaderText="Summe" SortExpression="Summe" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thats my Code and I get the Error Message that the Name or Entry Summe does not exist?

Comment: Run the query in SSMS and see if it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need an alias (as Summe):

```
SELECT SUM(Summe) as Summe, ItemObjektID FROM [Item] GROUP BY ItemObjektID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$    ConnectionStrings:SqlDataSource1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT SUM(Summe) as Summe, ItemObjektID FROM [Item] GROUP BY ItemObjektID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         Items:<br /><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ItemObjektID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8">
     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemObjektID" HeaderText="ItemObjektID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ItemObjektID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Summe" HeaderText="Summe" SortExpression="Summe" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```